# Flickr.photos.search() Error (GAE+JSF)

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, flickr

my problem is the folling one, I am trying to display a couple of images from flickr by using a tag. When I deploy the app I get a blank page. But by checking the browser's console I have found this:

```
(index):13
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=88f1c84…&tags=football&per_page=5&page…:1
```

And

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrApi is not defined at ?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=88f1c84…&tags=football&per_page=5&page…:1
```

I don't really know what this means at all...

```
<!DOCTYPE html >


<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Flickr</TITLE>

</head>
<body>

<script>
function jsonFlickrApi(rsp){
    window.rsp = rsp;
    var s = "";
    s = "total number is: "+rsp.photos.photo.length+"<br/>";

    for(var i=0;i&lt;rsp.photos.photo.length;i++){
        photo = rsp.photos.photo[i];
        t_url = "http://farm"+photo.farm+".static.flickr.com/"+photo.server+"/"+photo.id+"_"+photo.secret+"_"+"t.jpg";
        p_url = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/"+photo.owner+"/"+photo.id;
        s += '<a href="' + p_url+ '">' + 'img alt="'+photo.title+ '"src="'+t_url+'"/>'+'</a>';

    }
    document.writeln(s);
}   
</script>

<script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&#38;api_key=88f1c841c5e9acb6cccd8f1f81cf6950&#38;tags=football&#38;per_page=5&#38;page=1&#38;format=json&#38;api_sig=70c1245d615fa1dc6b254724dcbabfad"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
for(var i=0;i&lt;rsp.photos.photo.length;i++){
```

`&lt;` is a string character, when you want it to be the less than sign `<`.  So, change to:

```
for(var i=0;i<rsp.photos.photo.length;i++){
```

Comment: That is not a string character, that is how you code < in xhtml

Comment: There is nothing in your code, question, or `DOCTYPE` that tells me (or the page) that you want `XHTML`.  You are inside a javascript block, which is not interpreting the `<` character the way you intend.  Wrap it in a `/* <![CDATA[ */    /* ]]> */`  Try my solution and see what I mean.  It will work.